# Multiple ember apps with one login app

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I have multiple ember apps, but just one of them has the login page. I want to authenticate all of them with this unique page. How can I redirect other apps to an external login page using ember-simple-auth and redirect to the corresponding app after the authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom authenticator. In it's `authenticate` method I suggest to not redirect, but open a child window with login page. And that login page should be able to communicate with your ember app in some way (window.postMessage for example) in order to give your app auth token. Authenticator must wait until it receive answer (promise and timer will help with waiting). I used such method with google's oauth in node-webkit application (my authenticator opens google's oauth page where user prompted to give my app an access). I don't want to share a code because its too big, complex and have code specific to nw.js but I hope my answer will help. I used code of [oauth2 authenticator](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/addon/authenticators/oauth2-password-grant.js) to develop my own, it helped me a lot.